# How to show hidden columns only in editing or creation mode using material-table react?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Hi I using https://github.com/mbrn/material-table and I want to show hidden columns only in editing or creation mode, this is possible?

Comment: Certainly you can code to show columns only in Edit/Create mode and hide it in View mode. Alternatively you can create 2 separate components with separate column views for each

Comment: Certainly you can code to show columns only in Edit/Create mode and hide it in View mode. - How?

Comment: Did you get any lead ?

Answer (score 2):

use `columnsButton` in the options prop: https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/types/index.d.ts#L300

This will enable a button in the toolbar to toggle columns:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! This will allow user to hide columns, am I right? But is there a way to hide it from code? So user just won't see the column in view mode, but will be able to see and touch it from the edit mode.